# Making a program exit during a loop

Tags: java, loops, applet, exit

I recently was playing around with Java, and I made a program that runs in a loop. When I tried hitting the X in the corner to close it, nothing happened. I tried adding standard mouselistener code to make it exit, but it won't come through the loop. The program is simply a small square bouncing around the screen:

```
package mainPackage;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainClass extends JApplet{
    public static boolean isRunning = true;
    public static void startStop(){
        if(isRunning){
            isRunning = false;
        } else {
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Eclipse kept yelling at me.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3997547128895841169L;
    final static Color bg = Color.white;
    final static Color fg = Color.black;
            /*
     * The direction of the box; 1 is up-right, 2 is down-right, etc.
     */
    public static byte direction = 1;
            /*
             *The X and Y values start somewhat randomly.
             */
    public static short x = (short) (Math.random() * 150);
    public static short y = (short) (Math.random() * 150);
    public void init() {

        }
    public static void moveBall(){
        if(x >= 585){
            if(direction == 1){
                direction = 4;
            } else {
                direction = 3;
            }
        } else if(x <= 0){
            if(direction == 3){
                direction = 2;
            } else {
                direction = 1;
            }
        } else if(y <= 0){
            if(direction == 1){
                direction = 2;
            } else {
                direction = 3;
            }
        } else if(y >= 365){
            if(direction == 3){
                direction = 4;
            } else {
                direction = 1;
            }
        }
        if(direction == 1){
            x++; y--;
        } else if(direction == 2){ x++; y++;
        } else if(direction == 3){ x--; y++;
        } else if(direction == 4){ x--; y--;
        } else { System.out.println(direction); System.exit(5);}
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Color color = Color.black;
        Rectangle2D.Double a = new Rectangle2D.Double(250, 250, 10, 10);
        Rectangle2D.Double fill = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 600, 400);
        g2.setPaint(color);
        g2.fill(fill);
        while(isRunning){
            g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
            g2.fill(a);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            g2.setPaint(Color.black);
            g2.fill(a);
            a.setRect(x, y, 10, 10);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Test");
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setBounds(250, 250, 600, 400);
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JApplet applet = new MainClass();       
        jframe.getContentPane().add("Center", applet);
        while(isRunning){
            moveBall();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Interrupted.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Edit]I forgot to mention that when I exported it into an executable JAR file and then ran it, I had to open Task Manager, which then told me it was not responding, in order to close it.

Is there anyway to re-write this so that it can close?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not listening the close event. Try with this:

```
class WindowEventHandler extends WindowAdapter {
 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
  isRunnig = false;
 }
}
```

and

```
jframe.addWindowListener(new WindowEventHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep` and main loop in Swing EDT are bad idea. 
Use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).